# Image resource naming differs between Windows 7 and 8?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-7, windows-8

I have a WPF application that uses `png` images as resources. These images are added to my `csproj` "as link" in a folder named "resources" with the following properties

- Build Action: Resource
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

In my `xaml` files, they are referenced like this:

```
<Image Source="foo.png" />
```

This was sufficient to build and run using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. After installing Windows 8, the solution still builds successfully, but none of the images appear in the running application. If I change each `xaml` image reference to this, the images **do** apear:

```
<Image Source="resources/foo.png" />
```

So, what has changed between my Windows 7 and Windows 8 installs that affects this? Additionally, what approach can I take that will allow my application to build and run successfully on both Windows 7 and 8?

Comment: I guess you could use a pack URI to refer to the image in a more formal way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.85).aspx ... Would be interesting in hearing more of your findings about the changes between Windows 7 and Windows 8....i.e. what behaviour is broken in this area.

Comment: Did you change your directory structure?

Comment: not that i know of, it's a checkout of the same repo on different versions of windows

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that the file is added as a link in a folder called "resources", I'm not sure how it worked without the qualifying path before. Technically every relative Uri is a "pack" uri that is relative to the page trying to load it. I doubt the relative rules changed between framework versions, but I think you have three options:

1. Include the "resources" prefix if this works for both versions.
2. Get explicit with the pack Uri instead of using relative Uris and depending on the system to convert them (more [info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)).
3. Force the application to run under a specific runtime version (more [info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w519wzk.aspx)).